# Spring integration multithreading

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

Referring to my earlier question at URL - [Spring integration multithreading requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838347/spring-integration-multithreading-requirement) - I think I may have figured out the root cause of the issue.
**My requirement in brief** - 
Poll the database after a fixed delay of 1 sec and then publish very limited data to Tibco EMS queue.  Now from this EMS queue I have to do the following tasks all in multithreaded fashion :-  
i) consume the messages,  
ii) fetch the full data now from the database and 
iii) converting this data into json format.

**My design** -

```
`<int:channel id="dbchannel"/>   
    <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="dbchanneladapter"  
        channel="dbchannel"  data-source="datasource"  
        query="${selectquery}"  update="${updatequery}"  
        max-rows-per-poll="1000">  
        <int:poller id="dbchanneladapterpoller"  
            fixed-delay="1000">  
            <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionmanager" />  
        </int:poller>  
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>  
    <int:service-activator input-channel="dbchannel"
        output-channel="publishchannel" ref="jdbcmessagehandler" method="handleJdbcMessage" />  
    <bean id="jdbcmessagehandler" class="com.citigroup.handler.JdbcMessageHandler" />  

    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="publishchannel"/>  
    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="publishchanneladapter"
        channel="publishchannel" jms-template="publishrealtimefeedinternaljmstemplate" />  

    <int:channel id="subscribechannel"/>  
    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="subscribechanneladapter" destination="subscriberealtimeinternalqueue" 
        connection-factory="authenticationconnectionfactory" channel="subscribechannel" 
        concurrent-consumers="5" max-concurrent-consumers="5" />  
    <int:service-activator input-channel="subscribechannel"
        ref="subscribemessagehandler" method="logJMSMessage" />  
    <bean id="subscribemessagehandler" class="com.citigroup.handler.SubscribeJMSMessageHandler" />  
</beans>  

<bean id="authenticationconnectionfactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="username" value="test" />
        <property name="password" value="test123" />
    </bean>  

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName" value="app.jndi.testCF" />
</bean>  

<bean id="subscriberealtimeinternalqueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName"
        value="app.queue.testQueue" />
</bean>   
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tibjmsnaming://test01d.nam.nsroot.net:7222</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>`
```

**Issue** - 
Using message-driven-channel with concurrent consumers value set to 5. However, it looks like just one consumer thread (container-2) is created and is picking up the messages from EMS queue.  Please find below the log4j log -

16 Aug 2018 11:31:12,077 INFO SubscribeJMSMessageHandler [subscribechanneladapter.**container-2**][]:
 Total count of records read from Queue at this moment is 387 

 record#1:: [ID=7694066395]  
 record#2:: [ID=7694066423]
 .. .. ..
 record#387:: [ID=6147457333]

**Probable root cause here** - 
May be its the first step in the configuration where I am polling the database to fetch the data after a fixed-delay that's causing this multithreading issue. Referring to the logs above, my assumption here is since the number of records fetched is 387 and all these are bundled into a List object (List> message), it is being considered as just 1 message/payload instead of 387 different messages and that's why just one thread/container/consumer is picking up this bundled message. Reason for this assumption is the logs below -

GenericMessage [**payload=[{"ID":7694066395},{"ID":7694066423},{"ID":6147457333}**], 
 headers={json__ContentTypeId__=class org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap, jms_redelivered=false, json__TypeId__=class java.util.ArrayList, jms_destination=Queue[app.queue.testQueue], id=e034ba73-7781-b62c-0307-170099263068, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1534820792064, contentType=application/json, jms_messageId=ID:test.21415B667C051:40C149C0, timestamp=1534820792481}]

**Question** - 
Is my understanding of the root cause correct? If yes then what can be done to treat these 387 messages as individual messages (and not one List object of messages) and publish them one by one without impacting the transaction management?? 
I had discussed this issue with https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756547/artem-bilan in my earlier post on stackoverflow and I had to check this design by replacing Tibco EMS with ActiveMQ. However, ActiveMQ infrastructure is is still being analysed by our architecture team and so can't be used till its approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! Now I see what is your problem. The `int-jdbc:inbound-channel-Adapter` indeed returns a list of records it could select from the DB. And this whole list is sent as a single message to the JMS. That’s the reason how you see only one thread in the consumer side: there is just only one message to get from the queue.

If you would like to have separate messages for each pulled record, you need to consider to use a `<splitter>` in between JDBC polling operation and sending to JMS.

Comment: Hope use of `<splitter>` won't break the transaction if I use it between JDBC polling operation and sending to EMS queue. The way I have set the transaction in my design is like - The transaction begins when the first poll of database fetches say 10 records and it ends when these records are sent to Tibco EMS queue. Only after it is sent to EMS queue, the second poll should start and with it the second transaction. Please confirm

Comment: That’s correct, the transaction is there really per poll and is for the whole sub-flow as long as everything downstream is performed in the same polling thread

Comment: I have used `<splitter/>` for each pulled record. I can see multiple threads now. Thanks. 
One question here - I am using `<logging-channel-adapter logger-name="feedlogger" level="INFO" log-full-message="true"/>` to log the messages using log4j framework - Is there any way to log the 'id' of each message channel, used in my design, in the log file?

Comment: Let’s arrange that as a separate SO question!

Comment: I have arranged that as a separate SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038843/spring-integration-logging-message-channel-id