# Spring integration Logging message channel ID

Tags: spring-integration

I am using `<logging-channel-adapter logger-name="feedlogger" level="INFO" log-full-message="true"/>` to log full messages using log4j framework. 
Is there any way to log the 'id' of each and every message channel, used in spring intergration flow,  in the log file?

Thanks, 
Mitesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear. Channels are beans and if you would like to get their ids logged, there is just enough to turn on a `info` for the `org.springframework` and bean ids will be logged on the application start up. In addition Spring Integration with the `debug` for the `org.springframework.integration` shows log messages about subscribers on the channel during the same start up phase.

However if your question would sound like this:

> How to log channels each massage passes through?

Then you need to take a look into the [Message History](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history) EI pattern implementation.